# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException inspite of adding dependency

Tags: java, mysql, maven

My connection manager class is as follows:

```
package com.ideas.db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionManager {

    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null ; 


        //next two lines are always same
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/formsdb", "root", "root");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;

    }
}
```

and i have written following test for the above class:

```
package com.ideas.db;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ConnectionManagerTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldGetConnection(){
        ConnectionManager connectionManager= new ConnectionManager();
        Assert.assertNotNull(connectionManager.getConnection());
    }
}
```

I have added following dependency in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, I am still getting the error when I run the test

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:370)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.ideas.db.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:16)
    at com.ideas.db.ConnectionManagerTest.shouldGetConnection(ConnectionManagerTest.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:61)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:420)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.fill(Manifest.java:441)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:375)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:409)
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:376)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:199)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:944)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:450)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: @Abihabi87 No. See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html

Comment: In theory you don't even need to `Class.forName()` since the JDBC driver is compatible with version 4.0 and better of JDBC; it means that the driver should be registered automatically and you just have to `DriverManager.getConnection()`. The database in the JDBC URL will be registered for you. Still, as [Muel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39201667/1093528) says, here the problem is that your zip file cannot be read for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the MySQL jar file may corrupted:

`Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)`

Delete the JAR file from your local Maven repository and try running Maven again.

Answer (score 0):

Your ZIP file seems defective.

JAR files are essentially ZIP files. Remove the jar file from the local repository and reload it from the dependency server. You can also test the jar file using the jar application.

The essential exception is

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:61)
```

This means, your downloaded dependency cannot be properly unpacked/loaded.

Comment: But I have added dependency in pom.xml. there is no zip file

Comment: see my updated answer. I agree, the one liner was possibly too much information to be added to understand.